# Making notes visible when using a Tumblr theme that doesn't show them

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I have just created a Tumblr blog using the Indy theme. After creating a new post I noticed that the notes do not show up, just a short line. I tried searching for an option to make the notes visible, but I could not find it. As it was pointed out, apparently not all themes display notes.

How do I make the notes visible if using the Indy theme?

What changes do I have to make to its HTML?

Here is my blog if you need to see what I am talking about: 
`empathetic-moose.tumblr.com`

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit your theme and add the [code responsible for including notes](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#notes).

For the standard display, add `{PostNotes}` in the block responsible for displaying a single post, e.g. in `{block:Posts} … {/block:Posts}`.